# Good practices for designing private methode

Tags: c#, oop

Looking at some c# code from open and closed source project i see that private, and sometimes public methods are designed to recive parameters and not directly access the instance variable to extract the parameter they need

```
  class A
  {
    private B b;

    public void Methode1()
    {            
        Methode2(b.SomeProperty);
    }                

    private void Methode2(string param)
    {         
    }
  }
```

Is this considered as a good practice, or it's just a programming way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its normal. Consider also moving `Methode2` to class `B` ([Tell, don't ask](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TellDontAsk) principle):

```
 class A
  {
    private B b;

    public void Methode1()
    {            
        b.Methode2();
    }
  }
```

What is bad - passing whole object as parameter for method, when you need only value of it's property (don't pass to method more, than it needs for execution):

```
 class A
  {
    private B b;

    public void Methode1()
    {            
        Methode2(b);
    }                

    private void Methode2(B b)
    {
        // use b.SomeProperty         
    }
  }
```

Comment: isn't confusing whene passing the whole parametre whene just one or two parametres are needed?

Comment: @anouar204 sorry, didn't get the question

Comment: if the methode need only a small set of parameters from the class B isn't confusing to pass the whole instance?

Comment: @anouar204 if those parameters are related, then maybe its time to group them into some entity and pass to method (e.g. grouping zip, city and street to address entity). If parameters not related, but all belong to one object, then it's OK to pass whole object instead of several parameters (but if you need to pull many data from some object to execute operation, then consider moving method to object which already contains all data)

Comment: Moving Methode2 to B works, and is a way to go imo, but only if there is nothing else in Methode2 that depends on A. Otoh, if there are lots of places where you have to call `Methode2(b.SomeProperty)`, this is kind of at odds with DRY.

Comment: @anouar204 if Methode2 depends on `A` data also, thats up to you to decide whether move it (and pass some `A` data), or not. Sometimes it turns that creating third class `C` is good option (if Method2 naturally do not fit bot to `A` and `B`, or same logic implemented in several classes) :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no a "good practice" in regard of *this* subject.

This is a kind of method "overloading" (can not find exact term to define this), maintaining some of them private. That is.

In this concrete example *could* be that `Methode2(string param)` is also called from some other part of the class with a different from `b.SomeProperty` parameter.

So to avoid double code, the developer entroduced a new `Methode2(..)` method.

Comment: The code shown isn't using overloading at all. The method names are different.

Comment: can we consider the readability of the code a sufficient argument to use parameters instead of the instance variable?

Comment: @anouar204: don't see any readability benefits, if not you esplcitly specify what this method uses, but what if that method uses 10 members of the class ? Don't think adding 10 parameters to the method is readable. So I would say no, there is no any readability benefits, imo.

Comment: @Tigran i agree with you but what if the methode need only 1 or 2 parameters?

Comment: @anouar204: in this case it becomes *subjective* discussion :) It depends, in other words. Both of solutions has their pros and cons. One clearly stands what members the function uses (by declaring them like parameters), other avoid to declare unecessary parameters and just use class members internaly, maintaining clear function definition.